# Does Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem depend on measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know  Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem holds for Lebesgue measure. But, in general, does it hold for an general measure? For example, I know it holds for the counting measure, so we obtain the LDCT for infinite series.

Comment: yes of course, look at the proof..nothing depends on measure, just Fatou's lemma..which holds for an arbitrary measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the theorem is valid for any measure.  If you read the proof, nothing is used except countable additivity.